# Angular - $uibModal is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I created this controller

```
app.controller('headerCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$log', '$uibModal',  function($scope, $log, $uibModal){...}])
```

which gives the following error anytime i run it

```
Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- headerCtrl
```

According to angular, this may be due to a typo with the dependency name or an undefined dependency which is not the case here since ui.bootstrap is defined and spelled correctly

Here is my module

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngMap',
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngAnimate'
]);
```

However, when i remove '$uibModal' before the function like this

```
app.controller('headerCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log, $uibModal){...}])
```

and run

```
console.log($uibModal)
```

console returns undefined. I updated ui-bootstrap with bower but that didn't work. I haven't been able to create a modal because of this. How do I get $uibModal to be injected successfully by angular

Comment: suspect you still have an old version of `ui.bootstrap`. Older versions used `$modal` without `uib` in name. Try `$modal` instead and will know if it is older version

Comment: @charlietfl Oh my goodness, you were right i changed the controller back to its original form by adding '$uibModal' back to the controller but this time replacing all '$uibModal' with '$modal' and it worked. But my bower.json after the update showed "angular-bootstrap": "~1.1.2" How is it possible that $modal still worked?

Comment: @charlietfl I figured out why the updated version was not working. I am using gulp and didn't create a watch task for my bower components. So i when i updated it in the source folder, it did not reflect in the dist folder